# CosmosDB RequestUnit Consumption Mismatch

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I've run into an issue with RU consumption in CosmosDb. The Normalized RU Consumption view in Azure Insights got me confused. I hope someone can help to clarify.

Our application creates documents of 8kb in size. CosmosDb returns the request usage of 14 Request Units per Create. Some requests are a bit lighter, so avg RU is lower actually.

This create action is executed 280 times per minute, which is about 5 requests per second.
This would mean this process would consume 5 x 14 = 70 request units each second.
Currently there are no other queries running.

The total requests unit chart shows 12.5K RU's per 5 minutes. Which more or less corresponds to the calculated usage: 12500/5min/60sec=41.6 Request Units per second.

If I provision 5000 RU/s for that container, I actually provision 5000 Request Units per second, right? (RU/s is Request Units per Second?)
This means, the current setup would be consuming 70 of the 5000 units per second, which is 70/5000*100=1.4% of the provisioned capacity.

Now, If I look at the Insights screen in Azure portal under CosmosDb, it shows a chart "Normalized RU Consumption (max)' . This chart indicates that I'm using 40%-50% of the 5000 RU/s provisioned. If I lower the manual provisioned throughtput to 2000, the throttled counts starts being above 0. So it is clear we have some barrier there.

The difference between a) the calculation/requests charts  and b) consumption chart is almost a difference of 35 times.

Some further info:

- The total requests chart in azure shows that not more requests are
  performed.
- The partitionkey is synthetic yyyy-dd-<random 0..20>.
- TTL is 7 days.
- We have 1 physical partition and  20 logical partitions.
- Partitionkeys are evenly distributed
- Single region.
- Total data usage is 10GB (data + index).
- The app uses the REST API to create documents.

Can anyone explain this? Or have an idea how to fix this?

ps:

```
Partitionkey distribution in 5 minutes:
0 2021-05-06 75
1 2021-05-07 57
2 2021-05-05 50
3 2021-05-19 56
4 2021-05-08 64
5 2021-05-11 71
6 2021-05-09 56
7 2021-05-12 70
8 2021-05-01 61
9 2021-05-10 55
10 2021-05-17 55
11 2021-05-03 65
12 2021-05-02 60
13 2021-05-18 52
14 2021-05-15 54
15 2021-05-04 71
16 2021-05-14 65
17 2021-05-16 61
18 2021-05-13 45
Items checked: 1143. Partitionkeys encountered: 19
```

Update I: Usage of REST API
Update II:
I've done the research using log files as suggested by @NoahStahl.  Each request to cosmosdb is logged in the client object that does the actual HTTP request.  I did not find a hidden number of request units.  What I did find are the following numbers:

- It runs on two instances. Per minute these instances together handle 251 reguests.
- Total number of charged RU's in a minute are: 2693 (values between 9.71, 10.48, 12.95 ...).
- If we divide that by 60 (for seconds), it corresponds to 44.8833 Request Units consumed per second.

So it actually confirms the discrepancy as described before. It does not get close to the 40%-50% of the provisioned 5000RUs per second.

As a test, I also removed the logging entirely from this app. The Consumed RU's chart in Azure dropped to 0.  So I think it is safe to assume that all requests are coming from the app.

Update III:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Update IV
[image]

The request units in absolute numbers also corresponds to what I see in the logs. The time axis in this chart is 4 hours. So every point is 5 minutes. A value of +/- 12K RU in 5 minutes, corresponds to 40 RU per second.

Comment: You have RU/sec assumption correct. Just remember that the available RU for a container are divided across physical partitions. Do you have more than one physical partition? You mention 20 partitions - are those across multiple physical partitions? If so, this might explain what you're seeing. And this would show itself even more if one of your partitions was a *hot* partition.

Comment: Hello david. Thanks for your thoughts. It still uses only one physical partition (i’ll update the question)... the actual data stored is  less than 10gb. As for hot partition, i would guess this cant be the case since the synthetic pk includes a random generated number between 0 and 20.m, so it picks at random one of 20 lp’s. It should be even distributed.   Every create a random pk is defined. But perhaps i should investigate that further... but then, how could one hot partition multiply the consumed requests units?

Comment: Given the big difference between your expected throughput and throttling witnessed, it seems like you have some operations that are more expensive than you think, or more bursty. I'd try implementing more granular logging in the application code, e.g in this example https://youtu.be/Tht_RV5QPJ0?t=2964

Comment: Hello Noah, Thanks for the video, I watched the part you linked to and I'll follow that suggestion and get back. From your suggestion I deduce that you also think that provisioning 4000 RU/s actually means the app should be able to spend (or consume) 4000 RU each second right, so per hour x 3600? So if it consumes less then 100 RU per second (which I'll investigate further) it should not get anywhere near the provisioned amount yet? Sorry for asking this confirmation, but I was confused and started to doubt if this is actually correct reasoning.

Comment: @NoahStahl I've done the research using log files.  Each request to cosmosdb is logged in the client object that does the actual HTTP request.  I did not find a hidden number of request units.  What I did find are the following numbers. It runs on two instances  Per minute it has 251 reguests. Total number of charged RU's in a minute are: 2693 (values between 9.71, 10.48, 12.95 ...)  This corresponds to 44.8833 RUequest Units consumed per second. So it actually confirms the discrepancy. (I'll add this info to the question)

Comment: @Paul0515 The throughput uses a sliding per-second window. If you go over the max in the window, you have to wait until some amount of time to pay off the debt incurred. At that point writing is allowed again. This means, to my knowledge, that if you see throttling you are spiking above the max during a ~1 sec duration, whether from a single expensive request or burst of smaller ones.

Comment: To clarify, you can't necessarily look at averages. If during any second a spike occurs, it doesn't matter if the average for the surrounding minute was within limits. You'll still see throttle responses and associated performance hit on those requests.

Comment: Hello Noah, when I provision 4000 RU/s I don't see spikes (current situation). But the RU consumption is 40%-50% in the chart. That seems extremely high.  So, I did not reach the edge of what is provisiond, but I can not lower it to say 400 RU/s because then I get the 429's. I added the consumption chart image I get right now.

Comment: I added the consumption chart, total requests chart, the throttle chart. ... sometimes images say more than words... ;-)

Comment: @NoahStahl Following your remark, I checked the distribution in the logs again, and the numbers are spiking indeed. Not each second receives the same amount of requests. Not even close. In some seconds the load is much higher than average, and in most it is lower than average. Thank you for your comment, it seems this points to the rootcause.

Comment: In the metrics blade set the metric to `Normalized RU Consumption` and set the aggregation to `avg`.

Comment: Hello @404, thanks for the suggestion. Normalized RU Consumption AVG also shows averages per minute right? I did check that chart. Very informative, but it does not show spikes in specific seconds. And that is the mismatch. To throttle or not to throttle is based on usage/provisioning on a Second basis. The Normalized RU Consumption MAX actually does a better job at indicating the spikes in usage during a each second. You have to be careful and interpret that graph correctly. The issue is fixed ... I removed the spikes and the required amount to provision is on 400 RU/s, without throttling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make it clear this issue is fixed, I put the snippets from the comments here to clarify the solution:

@noahstahl added this comment:
Given the big difference between your expected throughput and throttling witnessed, it seems like you have some operations that are more expensive than you think, or more bursty. I'd try implementing more granular logging in the application code, e.g in this example youtu.be/Tht_RV5QPJ0?t=2964

The 'bursty' comment was the pointer to the solution. The avg numbers per minute are all OK, so there seems to be a big gap in expected usage vs required capacity provisioning. However if you look per second (by using the logs), it becomes clear that some seconds do not have any traffic, while other seconds are seeing traffic which is much higher in terms of RU's. By fixing these bursts, everything went back to 'as expected'.

As a side note, the video of @noahstahl was fun to watch. Thanks for sharing!